# Get open cursor information for non-privileged Oracle user

Tags: oracle, memory-leaks, database-administration

I want to implement some integration/unit tests for a Java 7 application that connects to an Oracle Database 12.1. The database user used for testing to connect to the database does not have DBA privileges (and I cannot grant them to him).

I want to make sure that the code executed by each unit test does not introduce any cursor leaks so I would like to execute a query like the following before and after each JUnit test case (using a @Before and @After annotation) and compare the values:

```
select a.value 
from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s 
where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and s.sid=a.sid and s.sid= sys_context('USERENV','SID') and b.name = 'opened cursors current'
```

The problem is that since the user running this query is not a DBA I get the following error when trying to run this query:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I tried looking the [USER_*](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-22FAAA6B-2181-47AE-8A10-6CF968B52CA4.htm#REFRN-GUID-22FAAA6B-2181-47AE-8A10-6CF968B52CA4) tables for relevant information but could not find anything. Is there a way in Oracle to get a user's open cursors if that user does not have DBA privileges?

Comment: Why don't you explicitly close cursor at the beginning of the program to avoid any leaks.

Comment: @XING I want an automated way to make sure that I or anybody else working on the code does not get sloppy and forget to close the cursors.

Comment: In that case i would say you really need a DBA privilege.  You can also create a procedure and ask DBA to execute it everytime you want to close cursor.